# How to have both Swift 2 and Swift 3 books in iBooks library

Tags: books, swift

I'm a professional software developer who is still supporting clients using Swift 2. However, I'd like to be getting up to speed on Swift 3 since clearly it is the wave of the future.

My copy of iBooks (on my Mac, dunno about my iOS devices) is currently the Swift 2 book, and when I go to the bookstore, it shows the Swift 3 version with a read button. When I click that it opens the Swift 2 book.

I see from another question that I can right-click on my Swift 2 book in iBooks, delete it, and then re-download from the app store in order to update to the Swift 3 book.

However, I need both versions to show up in my library, clearly named, and need to be able to open one or the other at will.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure iBooks offers an easy way to keep two versions of the same book from the iBooks Store around.

You could instead add the old version as an [ePub or PDF](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205751) copy. Apple makes the [Swift documentation available as an ePub on swift.org](https://swift.org/documentation/). That site only seems to have the latest version, but copies of the older versions can be found around the web. Here's one for example: [“The Swift Programming Language, Swift 2.2 Edition, Prerelease”](https://vk.com/doc266651156_437308217).

There’s also a blog post on [“Converting the Swift Programming Language to PDF”](http://ericasadun.com/2015/10/28/converting-the-swift-programming-language-to-pdf-2/) which offers these instructions for converting the iBooks Store file to a PDF yourself:

> 1. Go to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books`.
> 2. Once there, locate the 881256329 epub folder. You must use a non-beta version of the book. Beta versions are DRM’ed. If your version appears to be DRM’ed (a holdover from the beta period), delete it in iBooks and re-download.
> 3. Copy this epub folder to your desktop. Remove the epub extension, zip it, rename to epub. Apple uses a non-standard epub format, and these steps transform the book back to something Calibre can import and convert.
> 4. Drag this epub into Calibre.
> 5. Click Convert books, choose PDF.
> 6. In Page Setup, select default output profile, set margins to 72 on each side
> 7. In PDF Output, add printable TOC.
> 8. Click OK and let the conversion start

Comment: PDF files have pretty poor support in iBooks. No bookmarks, no highlights, and I seem to remember that tables of contents don't work correctly. Do ePub documents support those features. My vague memory is that they do. Maybe I need to extract the ePub version of my Swift 2 book, rename it, import the renamed version into iBooks, then delete the original and download the latest Swift 3 version.